# EFO error when using a library command, inside of a library command

Tags: python, keyboard, eof, python-sounddevice

So I have a project I've been working on that mixes the Audio library Sounddevice and the input library Keyboard.
By themselves I have been able to make things work, but when I mixed them I started running into trouble. Specifically if I take the keyboard hotkey command to try and trigger a sound effect it causes and EOF. Hotkeys being used to do other Keyboard commands work no matter what, but it seems to have trouble with mixing. I have been reading the docs for both but I cant find a clear cut system for overlapping the libraries. Any loops i have tried haven't seemed to work either, though many of them have been poorly written because I just don't know how to pull stuff like that from a seemingly unrelated segment. Here's what I have.

```
import keyboard 
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
fileC = 'C:\\Users\\**\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Project\\PianoC.wav'

keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', lambda: keyboard.wait)

keyboard.add_hotkey('n', lambda: keyboard.write(" Hello"))
keyboard.add_hotkey('j', lambda: keyboard.write(" Hi"))
keyboard.add_hotkey('i', lambda: keyboard.write(" Hey"))
#These three worked without problem of not being put in a loop

keyboard.add_hotkey('c', lambda: keyboard.write(data,fs = sf.read(fileC,dtype ='float32'))        
#This always gives an EFO
```

Comment: Please add the traceback message so we can see the error, the line and the calls that got you there.

Comment: It is literally just an EFO pop up window and the end of the last line.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was EOF so edited your question. I really can't help here.